# java process hogs both cpu and net speed

Tags: java, process

Recently, I had noticed that my net speed had become slower. In the network statistics of System Monitor the correct speed was shown. I used tools like nethogs to investigate which process had so much usage. It wasn't of much help because the processes which showed up were taking up nearly nothing of my speed.

Suddenly it occurred to me that a couple of weeks ago I had observed the java process hogging a lot of my cpu. I thought it might even change the fate of my net speed if I stopped it. So I went ahead and did that. Surprisingly, my speed returned to normal and my computer is still behaving normally.

```
root@saurabh-ubuntu:/home/saurabh# ps aux | grep java
tomcat7   1546  0.2  1.4 1915288 44708 ?       Sl   12:05   0:11 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
saurabh  14757  222 23.2 3481076 700356 ?      SNl  13:19   6:09 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=0 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=0 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms60m -Xmx512m -Djava.library.path=lib -classpath wrapper.jar:bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar:freenet-ext.jar:freenet.jar -Dwrapper.key=liPhWRMzGh3wcYvE -Dwrapper.backend=pipe -Dwrapper.disable_console_input=TRUE -Dwrapper.pid=1298 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.20 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.arch=x86 -Dwrapper.ignore_signals=TRUE -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=3 freenet.node.NodeStarter freenet.ini
root     16561  0.0  0.0  16896   928 pts/1    S+   13:22   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

I don't know much about this, but stopping the java process would not make something not work I hope?
If yes, then how can I stop it from appearing again?

EDIT:
If I end or kill that process, it starts again. Only if I stop it it stays stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Freenet was causing the issue. I removed it, and now everything works fine.
Thanks to this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=792676). Also, the process did not restart once I killed it. So, it did the trick!